# If(data..) doesnt work with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

my Console on Server Print "my: false" "my: true" thats the Buttonvalue from Webbrowser

but if (data...) doesnt work with =/==/===. And a test with substring is also not running with error.

server.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        if (data=="my :true")
        {led.setHigh();}

        if (data=="my: false")
        {led.setLow();}

        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

client.js

```
socket.emit('my other event', { my:data.value });
```

Comment: If you write `data` to the console using `console.log(data)` you'll likely find that it's an object containing a key of `my` with the value `true`, hence you need to check `data.my === true`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access `data.my`. The `data` that is received by the server is a dynamic object, and `my` is a property of that object like so:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        if (data.my == true) //data.my is a boolean right?
            led.setHigh();
        else
            led.setLow();

        console.log(data); //Will output an object
    });
});
```